# How to know if a container is running on a leader kube-scheduler pod of a HA cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kube-scheduler

I have a HA cluster(say 3 masters with 1 kubes-scheduler pod on each master). There is a container running in each kube-scheduler pod. 
Inside this container, there two problems need to be solved here:

1. How to know which kube-scheduler pod the container is running on?
2. How to know if the kube-scheduler this container is running on is a leader?

I know the "holderIdentity" field of the "...kubernetes.io/leader" annotation of the pod will tell the ID of the leader. Then the only question is how to know which pod the container is running on.
Or there is a way I can simply know if the pod I'm running is a leader.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the logs of `kube-scheduler`.
You shall see `lock is held by <HolderIdentity> and has not yet expired` in the logs of non-leader Pods. And also `successfully acquired lease` or `successfully renewed lease` in the leader Pod logs.

Comment: Is is possible that both these two kinds of log exist because the leadership changed on this pod?